# В MySql 5.7 если один из элементов запроса пустой не производится запись

Tags: mysql

В MySql 5.7 при запросе INSERT INTO или UPDATE если хоть одно значение пустое, запись не производится. Например INSERT INTO `test`(`test_1`, `test_2`) VALUES ('1','') Как это можно победить? Благодарю!

Comment: *Как это можно победить?* Контролировать надо свои параметры, прежде чем пытаться их вставлять.

Comment: Можно обойтись без глупых комментариев? Не знаете, не понимаете в чем суть вопроса, просто воздержитесь от комментария.

Comment: Нельзя. Какой вопрос - такой и комментарий. Вот если бы кто-то не поленился написать, откуда берутся параметры, как получается, что один из них "пустой", как именно он заносится в запрос - тогда был бы предметный разговор.

Comment: Почему-то для alex все понятно и он дал ответ по сути. А вам ничего не понятно. Запрос прямо написан в вверху, в phpMyAdmin в вкладку SQL вставляю, нажимаю кнопку "вперед" и выдает ошибку. Требует чтобы не было пустого значения. Уже и ставил NULL - да и создавал заново таблицу. Ничего не помогает. За то в другой таблице в этой же БД все срабатывает без проблем.

Comment: *и выдает ошибку* И текст ошибки - это военная тайна, которую никогда, никому и ни за что... *в другой таблице в этой же БД все срабатывает без проблем* Значит, поле в другой таблице имеет default value. *для alex все понятно и он дал ответ по сути* Ещё скажи, что помогло...

Comment: А что выдается в MySQL Workbench?

Comment: номер ошибки #1364 Field 'test_2' doesn't have a default value. Не имеет во второй таблице там никакого  default value (значения по умолчанию) и срабатывает, тут даже со значением NULL не срабатывает, хотя в одной из таблиц реагирует на NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не побеждается это никак кроме как заполнением всех полей. При чем в исходном запросе, применение значений по умолчанию в phpMyAdmin не помогает. Только исключительно:

if ($_POST['test'] == 0) $test = 'значение по умолчанию';

else $test = $_POST['test'];

INSERT INTO test(test_1, test_2) VALUES ('1', $test)

В чем проблема? Хостер на свое усмотрение увеличивает строгость синтаксиса для базы данных, вот и запрос требует отсутствия пустых значений. После обращения к хостеру он любезно понизил строгость и все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Надо изменить поле `test_2`, чтобы оно принимало `NULL` значения.

```
alter table test modify column test_2 VARCHAR(256);
```